# Directus: How to access a collection item in PHP to create Meta tags for social media?

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph, directus

I'm using **Directus** for the first time, using the REST api to develop on the frontend. Right now I'm trying to find a way to create the OpenGraph tags for Facebook and social media.

My understanding is that I must do it in PHP, but can't find an way to access and filter the collection item I need to create the tags.

In php I know how the get the slug I'm supposed to use to filter. But don't know how to get inside the collections from a blank PHP file located in the **public** directory.

Any hint?

thanks